# NullReferenceException on page initialization if I use OnInitializedAsync method

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-3.0

I have a simple application but it stops working  on page initialization with error

**NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Site.Shared.MainLayout.BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder __builder)**
Error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/826zs.png)

But there is nothing complicated in the code.
App.razor:

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
    </Found>
  <NotFound>
      <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
          <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
      </LayoutView>
  </NotFound>
```

_Host.cshtml:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dH8Jl.png)

MainLayout.razor:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2mns.png)

StartUpService.cs:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDJIp.png)

page.GetPageGlobalAsync() is working well, I can pass this method in the debug mode.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJ77D.png)

But after I have this error. And have no idea what is the reason and how can I get more information about what is wrong.

UPD

If I change code to:

```
PageGlobal page =  new PageGlobal()
```

And it started working but OnInitializedAsync is the async method, why I cannot use async-await methods in the OnInitializedAsync method?

Comment: Do not post code as images, that doesn't google well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blazor problem rendering data returned from Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56289870/blazor-problem-rendering-data-returned-from-web-api)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your page is trying to render `@pageGlobal.Title`, before it's even got it from the async method. That's why if you do `pageGlobal = new PageGlobal();` it doesn't crash.

Change it to this:

```
<div class="top-row h3">
    @if(pageGlobal != null)
    {
        pageGlobal.Title
    }
</div>
```

Or if you want a one liner:

```
<div class="top-row h3">
    @pageGlobal?.Title
</div>
```

Comment: You are right. Hmm, this error is really confusing. Interesting, on the other page the similar error is understandable "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Site.Shared.NavMenu.BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder __builder) in NavMenu.razor
@foreach (var service in pageGlobal.Person.Services)"

Comment: Adding this condition check actually helped me load the page. I still don't understand why it doen't work even if I have data. It gives error even before trying to render when I add a loop on the page . If I remove loop, loading data in varible takes place.

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to use `Task.Run` when you're doing `Async` programming. Try to use `Task.FromResult` in `GetPageGlobalAsync` instead of `Task.Run`

```
 public async Task<PageGlobal> GetPageGlobalAsync()
    {
        return await Task.FromResult( new PageGlobal());
    }
```